# ¿Cómo cambiar el color de fondo de wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Sabe alguien cómo se puede cambiar el color de fondo de wordpress al gusto del usuario, por ejemplo por #ffdead? Me refiero al fondo completo del blog, incluido el marco. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

Saludos,

Para hacerlo de manera sencilla te recomiendo lo siguiente:

1.- instalar el plugin CSS editor de Site Origin https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/so-css/

2.- ir para Apariencia -> Custom CSS

3.- Introducir el codigo CSS que en este caso sería:

body{ background-color: #ffdead; }

4.- Guardar

Listo!

Espero te sirva (y)

Answer (score 1):

Información extraída de: [goDaddy](https://es.godaddy.com/help/cambiar-el-color-de-fondo-del-tema-en-wordpress-26442)

Cambiar el color de fondo del tema en WordPress.

Puede cambiar el color de fondo de un sitio de WordPress modificando el CSS

1. Antes de realizar cambios en un tema de WordPress, agregar un tema
   secundario.
2. Inicie sesión en WordPress.
3. Vaya a apariencia > Editor.
4. Introduzca el CSS para cambiar el color de fondo. A continuación
   encontrará código de ejemplo:

   ```
   .site {
       background-color: ffdead;
   }
   ```

   `.site` es la clase de css para todo el sitio.
   `ffdead` es el código hexadecimal para el color que desea utilizar.
5. Haga clic en el archivo de actualización.